# When to call Javascript programatically using code behind

Tags: asp.net, .net

In which scenario are we required to call Javascript programatically using code behind ? I am aware of RegisterStartupScript and RegisterClientScriptBlock methods and the difference between them. However, I would like to know for what purpose I can use them in my application.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `RegisterStartupScript` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to dynamically render some javascript on the page and execute it on page load based on some condition known on the server while the page is being rendered.

For example you might want to display some notification because a certain event happened.

You can solve the same problem in different ways, ie. AJAX long poll. Remember that `RegisterStartupScript` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock` were 'invented' a long time ago for ASP.NET web forms when more modern technical solution were not so widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're using you cannot call JS from code behind. You could only cause a script to start when the page is loaded at client. This is equivalent to add
...

All code behind methods are just wrappers to help you add some javascript dynamically allowing to construct script accordingly to some conditions. The alternative is to add all necessary code and to use only the part currently needed which will cause more traffic and load delay.

Answer (score 0):

We can use javascript from code behind in many cases, for example                           strScript = "" & _
            "window.opener.FillStaff)"()

The above code can be used to fill the controls of parent page of any click event at server side.